# How to surpress AlertDialog to show again when back key is pressed (transition between activitiesú

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
    // To open Recog, new activity
public void openRecog(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this,FunctionActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);


        // WARNING
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.warningTitle)
                .setMessage(R.string.warningRecogMessage)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.warningMessageAccept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }

                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();


}
```

It should basically show some warning when button is pressed in MainMenuActivity, before FunctionActivity is launched. Problem is that only way to get back from FunctionActivity to MainMenuActivity is to hit back key, which shows Warning again. Is there some way to surpress warning from showing when back key is pressed? I could not figure out anything... Thanks

Comment: are you calling this when back button is pressed right? And what do you mean by "surpress to show again? "

Comment: Nope, this is called when user hits ImageButton in the menu. Then the warning is shown and another activity started. But then user has to hit android back button to return back to the menu activity. Issue is that warning is shown in that transition back and I would like it to just to return to menu without showing that alert again.

Comment: ohkay, so the problem is warning again shown when you come back right?

Comment: Yeah, exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that issue was that as Dialogs are async, It was not dismissing at all. Therefore I have created listener like this

```
 public class DialogOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this,ClassifierActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This one is starting activity right after dismiss is completed. Anyway, kudos to @Kaushal28 for his time and willingness to help. Have a good day, sir :).

Comment: nice observation. plus one for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one trick here. Override the `onBackPressed()` method of your second activity as following:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_SECOND_ACTIVITY.this, YOUR_FIRSTACTIVITY.class);
    intent.putExtra("checker", true);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

So you are basically passing boolean to indicate that you are coming to first activity by pressing back. So in first activity, you have to receive the boolean in onResume method and when you are creating dialogue, first check this boolean in true or false, like this:

```
public boolean checker = false;
...
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // put your code here...
    checker = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("checker"); //this should be same as you given in 2nd activity
 }
```

So if boolean is false, you are safe to open our warning, like this:

```
if(!checker){
    //warning code... 
} else {
    //Do nothing because you are coming from 2nd activity. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this might do the trick but the issue is that FirstActivity can be resumed from lot of other activities - so this does not seem to be viable option...

Comment: That will not cause the problem because you are sending boolean from a single activity. So when other activities will resume it, the boolean will not be updated.

Comment: Okay so you are saying you have to add this code in each activity... then yes for this trick, long code will be the problem.

Comment: I would take it as a last resort, but I do not believe that there is no cleaner solution how to handle dismissed dialog when activity is resumed. It makes no sense to me :). But anyway, thanks for your help, appreciate it.

Comment: @bazinac 
 
i didn't say there is no other solution.But this is what I can suggest you. :)